# Programmatically Edit a .webarchive File

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, safari, flash-builder, webarchive

I'm building an AIR app using Actionscript and I want to programmatically insert a piece of text into a .webarchive file. The problem is that every time I insert the text, the file somehow gets corrupted. The code I'm using looks like this:

```
var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();                       
stream.open(file, FileMode.READ);   
var body:ByteArray = new ByteArray();                       
stream.readBytes(body, file.size);                      
var result:Array = pattern.exec(body.toString());                   
var new_body:String;                        
new_body = body.toString().replace(pattern, "replacing text here!</body>"); 
stream.close();                     
stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);                      
stream.writeUTFBytes(new_body);                     
stream.close();
```

I'm guessing the problem has to do with the encoding of the .webarchive file. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should always use `stream.readUTFBytes()` or `stream.readUTF()` when reading text information from files. I'm guessing some actual encoding issues arise when you convert bytes to string in your code. The correct code would be:

```
var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();                       
stream.open(file, FileMode.READ);   
var body:String = stream.readUTFBytes(stream.bytesAvailable);   
stream.close();               
var new_body:String = body.replace(pattern, "replacing text here!</body>");  
stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);                      
stream.writeUTFBytes(new_body);                     
stream.close();
```